# How can I do instructions in function of the result of a test .gz? LINUX

Tags: linux, compression, corruption

i have a .gz file. I want to know whether the .gz is corrupted or not.
If it is corrupted I need to do something and if it is not, i need to do other things. 
My script is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gunzip --test  file.gz
if [[ I DON´T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE ]];
then
//THINGS TO DO IF FILE.GZ IS NOT CORRUPTED
else
//THINGS TO DO IF FILE.GZ IS CORRUPTED
fi
```

How can I do the condition of the if? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
if gunzip --test file.gz
then
//THINGS TO DO IF FILE.GZ IS NOT CORRUPTED
else
//THINGS TO DO IF FILE.GZ IS CORRUPTED
fi
```

Comment: I get the error "syntax error: unexpected end of file" why?